# Sidebar Is Dropping Below Content Area

Tags: css

I am trying to add a sidebar to both the left and right of my content area. A page that I am currently working on can be found [here](https://www.twoguysplayingzelda.com/news/which-incarnation-of-link-is-the-strongest-in-the-nintendo-legend-of-zelda-franchise/). You will notice the right sidebar below the content area (it has the word test in it twice). I think the issue lies in div class="section-inner". No matter what I do, it always applies a margin which I think is dropping the sidebar down below the content. Below is the CSS for that section and the sidebar. Can someone please help me because I have ran out of ideas. Thanks!

```
.section-inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 10%;
}

.sidebar .widget:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}

.sidebar .widget {
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css snippet

```css
.section-inner {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.section-inner .content {
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
}

.section-inner .sidebar {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-inner">
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

or with flex

```css
.section-inner {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.section-inner .content {
  flex-basis: 90%;
}

.section-inner .sidebar {
  flex-basis: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-inner">
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `body.single .content` set to 100% width.  Getting rid of that or setting to a fixed width, will allow the room for the right column.